# Group two dfs based on dates that closely match

Tags: r, dataframe, merging-data

These are subsets of two dataframes.

df1:

| plot | mean_first_flower_date | gdd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-07-15 | 60 |
| 1 | 2019-07-21 | 50 |
| 1 | 2019-07-23 | 78 |
| 2 | 2019-05-13 | 100 |
| 2 | 2019-05-22 | 173 |
| 2 | 2019-05-25 | 245 |

(cont.)

df2:

| plot | date | flowers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **2019-07-12** | 2 |
| 1 | **2019-07-13** | 9 |
| 1 | **2019-07-14** | 3 |
| 1 | 2019-07-15 | 3 |
| 2 | **2019-05-12** | 10 |
| 2 | 2019-05-13 | 10 |
| 2 | **2019-05-14** | 14 |
| 2 | **2019-05-15** | 17 |

(cont.)

df2 has some matching dates with df1 but sometimes the dates are off for one or a couple days (highlighted in bold).

I would like to group both dfs based on both 'date' and 'plot', keeping df2, without losing 'gdd' data from df1.

This will happen if, for example, I inner_join both dfs because the dates will not match.

So if a date in df1 is one to three days earlier or later than what it's possible to match in df2, it's fine because the dates are relatively close. This is tricky because I want this data replacement only if there is not data available in df1 for that data range.

My goal is to have something like this:

| plot | date | flowers | gdd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **2019-07-12** | 2 | **60** |
| 1 | **2019-07-13** | 9 | **60** |
| 1 | **2019-07-14** | 3 | **60** |
| 1 | 2019-07-15 | 3 | 60 |
| 2 | **2019-05-12** | 10 | **100** |
| 2 | 2019-05-13 | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | **2019-05-14** | 14 | **100** |
| 2 | **2019-05-15** | 17 | **100** |

Is it possible to do?

I greatly appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Should the dates for plot==2 in `df1` be in May instead of July?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: You want to fill `NA`s in resulting join, but what's the criteria for filling/adopting in case where there are two or more values in one plot?

Answer (score 1):

I think a 'rolling join' from the *data.table* package can handle this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[, mean_first_flower_date := as.Date(mean_first_flower_date)]
df2[, date := as.Date(date)]

df1[df2, on=c("plot","mean_first_flower_date==date"), roll=3, rollends=TRUE]

#   plot mean_first_flower_date gdd flowers
#1:    1             2019-07-12  60       2
#2:    1             2019-07-13  60       9
#3:    1             2019-07-14  60       3
#4:    1             2019-07-15  60       3
#5:    2             2019-05-12 100      10
#6:    2             2019-05-13 100      10
#7:    2             2019-05-14 100      14
#8:    2             2019-05-15 100      17
```

Using this data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="plot  mean_first_flower_date  gdd
1  2019-07-15  60
1  2019-07-21  50
1  2019-07-23  78
2  2019-05-13  100
2  2019-05-22  173
2  2019-05-25  245", header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text="plot  date  flowers
1  2019-07-12  2
1  2019-07-13  9
1  2019-07-14  3
1  2019-07-15  3
2  2019-05-12  10
2  2019-05-13  10
2  2019-05-14  14
2  2019-05-15  17", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I got this message after running the last line in the code:Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 33674 rows; more than 31079 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: Try adding the suggested argument to the call - `df1[df2, ..., allow.cartesian=TRUE]` as  the message says. Or *Check for duplicate key values* in the `mean_first_flower_date` - if you have many dates matching to many +3/-3 date ranges you will get duplication.

Comment: @user3508884 Please share some rows where more than one row matches in one plot.  In the sample data shared, there is only one match per plot.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fill` from `dplyr`.  use this syntax

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = c("plot" = "plot", "date" = "mean_first_flower_date")) %>%
  fill(gdd, .direction = "up")

  plot       date flowers gdd
1    1 2019-07-12       2  60
2    1 2019-07-13       9  60
3    1 2019-07-14       3  60
4    1 2019-07-15       3  60
5    2 2019-05-12      10 100
6    2 2019-05-13      10 100
7    2 2019-05-14      14  NA
8    2 2019-05-15      17  NA
```

As you can notice there are two `NA`s in the last two rows which shouldn't be there if you'll join your actual `df2` where these rows will be filled by `173` as there will be a match for `2019-05-22`.  Still if you want to fill the last NA rows, if any, you can use `fill` again with `.direction = "down"`

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = c("plot" = "plot", "date" = "mean_first_flower_date")) %>%
  fill(gdd, .direction = "up") %>% fill(gdd, .direction = "down")

  plot       date flowers gdd
1    1 2019-07-12       2  60
2    1 2019-07-13       9  60
3    1 2019-07-14       3  60
4    1 2019-07-15       3  60
5    2 2019-05-12      10 100
6    2 2019-05-13      10 100
7    2 2019-05-14      14 100
8    2 2019-05-15      17 100
```